# Не получается отправить ответ в viber ASP.NET CORE

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net, asp.net-core, viber

Нужно отправить обратный ответ при событии conversation_started, не пойму как правильно отправить, не приходит сообщение в viber. В postman отправлял json и в качестве ответа он возвращает json. Как указано здесь - https://developers.viber.com/docs/api/rest-bot-api/#sending-a-welcome-message
Возможно, я не правильно понял, как отправить ответ. Не знаю, как сделать правильно, если знаете - пишите. Спасибо.

П.С.
В данном примере я не использую фильтр, чтобы поймать какое событие пришло, оно и с фильтром также не работало.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

На последней картинке это ответ моего сервера.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если кто-то попадет в такую же ситуацию с адским вайбером.
Что вайбер тупит и не принимает мой ответ на событие "conversation_started" и не публикует сообщение. И вариант работы такой, что сообщение можно отправить на это событие просто, как обычное сообщение, но один раз, если клиент не подписался. В документации все обратное, они отрицают, что нельзя отправлять, если не подписан, а на событие "conversation_started" нужно отправлять ответом json. 
Будет примерно так, насколько я знаю.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Post([FromBody] JObject data)
    {
       Message.Result = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(data);
        //Task<string> dataToString = Task.Run(() => JsonConvert.SerializeObject(data));
        //Task<CallBack> callBack = Task.Run(() => JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<CallBack>(dataToString.Result));
      string dataToString = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(data);
       Task<CallBack> callBack =Task.Run(() => JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<CallBack>(dataToString));
        await Task.Run(() => Initialization.CallBackInitializationAsync= callBack);


        // Message.Result= Request.Headers["X-Viber-Content-Signature"];

        if (callBack.Result.Event == EventType.ConversationStarted)
        {
            viber = new Viber(callBack.Result);
            viber.Start();
            await viber.SendTextMessageAsync();
        }
        return Ok();

    }
```